# JSON string doesn't get processed with JQuery parseJSON() no error, no nothing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, response

I've been checking around stackoverflow to see if there is similar problem, but noone seems to have it. 
I read field from mysql table where i have my JSON string. The string itself is in format:

```
{"width":"10", "height":"20", "angle":"10", "solution":"vertical"}
```

And this is the jquery part of the script:

```
function readJSON(id) {
return $.ajax({
 url: "/core/reader.php?id=" + id,
 method: "GET",
 dataType: "html"
})
}

call = readJSON(4);
call.success(function(response){
    alert(response); //returns string in alert window
    var jsondata = $.parseJSON(response);
    alert(jsondata.width); //should return value of width (10), but nothing happens
});
```

Does anyone have a clue what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are usign Firefox or chrome, they have an "inspect element" tool that will allow you to view "Network" calls. Your dataType is set to html, I would change that to json.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you all for your answers. I had a problem in actual data. I had some key:value, where value had some control characters in it. So JSON string wasnt really compatible with JSON standards. Its well described [here](http://json.org/).

I've changed my php script, to replace those strings if they exist and now it all runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
alert(jsondata.width);
```

use this

```
alert(jsondata['width']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try change your datatype become like this:

```
function readJSON(id) {
return $.ajax({
 url: "/core/reader.php?id=" + id,
 method: "GET",
 dataType: "json"
});
}
```

before you use html datatype, while you use json to return data.